# Populating A New Object With Existing Objects Data

Tags: c#, oop

I have a service that is returning a custom object called "UserSettings" In my application I want to add more properties to the "UserSettings" object so I created a new object called "MyUserSettings" that inherits from "UserSettings" now I want to populate my new object with the existing data held in "UserSettings" and the new data I have for my new properties. I do not want to have to map each property one by one to the same property in the new object like this..

```
_MyUserSettings.Name=_UserSettings.Name;
```

Is there a way or better approach to what I am doing to populate ALL the properties of the existing object into my new object in one shot??

Comment: The other obvious option that springs to mind is to keep a reference to the original UserSettings inside MyUserSettings and then create properties in that which map through to the original object. However this is likely to be as much repetitive code as the way you have already thought of...

Comment: Right create a UserSettings property inside the new object will do it, but is this the right way to be doing things?

Comment: @NickLaMarca: Well, given the criteria "I do not want to have to map each property one by one to the same property in the new object" I can't see any other simple options (Adam talks about reflection below) but I would personally go for the copy one by one though with the clarification that has been made in the answers below that you put it in a constructor and don't write that code out each time you create a `MyUserSettings` object.

Comment: @Chris I'd first try AutoMapper, it might be an entirely codeless solution (it talks about a guessing algorithm for mapping types, in this instance, it should be able to guess easily).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use Copy Constructor pattern. It would give you an other benefit - you do not need public property setters so object becomes immutable.

```
public MyUserSettings(UserSettings baseSettings)
{
    // TODO: set all properties
}
```

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought that he might not be doing it in a constructor already. There is still the need to map each property one by one here I believe but you'd only ever have to do it once at least...

Comment: Do it once and keep it simple

Comment: Yup. This is definitely the best way to do it though the original post did say without mapping the properties one by one so it may fail that criteria depending on what the OP thinks...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is the only way, however, the specific mechanism can change. There are a numerous ways (not listing them all):

- Copy constructor, that takes an item and does this manual copying of fields across.
- Use reflection to have a more generic mechanism of achieving the same.
- Use something like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

They all boil down to pretty much doing the same thing.

If the `UserSettings` is actually a `MyUserSettings` then you can simply cast it:

```
var mySettings = (MyUserSettings)settings;
```

However, this will fail if `UserSettings` is really `UserSettings`.